# What happend to my changes after git stash push

Tags: git

I could swear `git stash push` destroyed my work.

Here's what happened. After about two and a half hours of working on some stuff this morning which turned out to be more complicated than expected, I decided to create a new branch off of the one that it was based on to test before committing changes.

So, I save the file (a Jupyter Notebook). I run `git stash push -m "Move to new branch."` Then I create a new branch (using VSCode.) I checkout the new branch. I run `git stash pop` and open the notebook.

Incidentally, before I even noticed that the changes were not actually in the notebook, I immediately committed them to the new branch. The notebook did appear to be modified by running `git stash pop` but none of the recent changes are there.

Here's the output from the git pop, lightly edited to remove actual file/branch names...

```
On branch new_branch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   notebook.ipynb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (a9044f83c9bf2ef48182c8fbe0715dbabaa2f4fd)
```

Anyway, `git stash` says "git-stash - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away" but none of the changes I just saved were there.

What did I miss? And is there any way to get the changes back or did the get eaten?

Comment: Why did you stash?

Comment: just to avoid an accidental garbage collection of commit `a9044f83...`, give it a name (a tag or a branch), for example : `git tag enquire/stash a9044f83`

Comment: Did that stash contain the commit you think ? you can inspect that commit : `git stash show a9044f83`. Do also inspect the list of your stashes : `git stash list`, and check if the stash you expect isn't listed there.

Comment: @matt Isn't the point to put the stuff that you don't yet want to commit so that you can get back later? I wanted to put the changes on a different branch.

Comment: Then just make the new branch and switch to it. No need to stash. Stash can destroy work, depending on your untracked and gitignore status. Making a new branch from head and switching to it leaves your work intact.

Comment: Ever since I looked into the innards of `git stash`, I've considered it a command best to be avoided. :-) A lot of people like it a lot, though.

Comment: What is reliable about Git is _commits that you create_. That's where known material is saved. Now, there are emergency times when `stash` might be needed, but this was not one of those. And `git stash` explicitly _deletes uncommitted work from your working tree._ That's a thing to do? Sure, Git might put that uncommitted work somewhere else where you can retrieve it, but sometimes maybe not. None of that helps you, alas, and obviously we don't know what exactly happened to your files; if we did, you'd be getting answers.

Comment: @matt : on my machine at least, the reference after `Dropped refs/satsh@{0} ...` *does* point at what that stash was (confirmed with git 2.27 and git 2.32)

Comment: @matt I'm totally confused by the purpose of git stash, if you are correct about this. Why would I ever need to stash committed work? Why does the documentation say "git-stash - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away" as if it doesn't not delete the dirty stuff, if you are correct? The examples in git's own documentation suggest that one can ```git stash``` at any moment, check out to another branch, return and run ```git apply``` to pick up where you left off.

Comment: @philosofool, you are not alone.  I have learned `git` in a fairly advanced way and I'm very comfortable with it.  I use `git` in pretty advanced ways on a regular basis and have even contributed code to the `git` project.  I literally `never` use `stash`.  All it does is create commits.  I can do that on my own.  I'd rather be able to see my commits in a straightforward manner, not have them hidden behind an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: @JoelFan In view of that, when I need to do like I did today, is it best to add everything to a single commit ```-m "WIP, reset --soft later```, create a new branch, ```reset --soft``` and then just keep working? When merging to the base branch, I would ```reset --hard``` before the merge to eliminate conflicts.

Comment: Why not just create the branch with `git checkout -b my-new-branch` then `git add .`, then `git commit`?  The result will be a new branch based on the last commit of the old branch, with your new work being the first new commit of the new branch.

Answer (score 1):

To see what was in the stash that you dropped when you ran `git stash pop`, inspect the commit `e9044f83...` mentioned in your terminal. For example :

```
# have a view of what files were "saved" in that commit :
git log --graph --oneline --name-status e9044f83

# check the content of 'notebook.ipynb' in that commit :
git show e9044f83:notebook.ipynb

# check the content that was *staged* when you stashed :
git show e9044f83^2:notebook.ipynb
```

If the changes in your file aren't there, perhaps you ran `git stash` *twice* and the content of the file you are looking for are in older stashes. To inspect other stashes :

```
# this will list the stashes you currently have :
$ git stash list

# 'git stash show' and 'git stash show -p' will show you what is stored
# in a given stash :
$ git stash show stash@{0}
$ git stash show stash@{1}
...

# 'git show [commit]:notebook.ipynb' will show you the content of that file :
$ git show stash@{0}:notebook.ipynb
$ git show stash@{1}:notebook.ipynb
...
```

---

After running `git stash pop`, your stash commit (`a9044f83...`) is not referenced by anything anymore, and is not part of a reflog, so git's garbage collection can collect it sooner than other commits.

If you want to preserve that commit, create a reference (a branch or a tag, or something else if you feel like it ...) that points at it. For example :

```
# you will now have a tag named 'keepme' which points at that commit :
git tag keepme e9044f83
```

---

If the changes you are looking for aren't in the stash, perhaps they have been committed somewhere else. In that case check your reflog :

```
git reflog
```

and search for the content of your notebook there.

Comment: @matt : let's not confuse things : your remark is correct regarding the message stored with the stash -- the one you will see in `git stash list`, or `git show stash`. The *other* message : `Dropped refs/stash@{0} (a9044f...)`, which is printed on the terminal when you run `git stash pop`, however, *is* the id of the stash which was dropped. If you inspect *that* one, you will see what you had in your stash.

Comment: Yes, totally. I did get confused by exactly that. I still blame Git for having a weird message when you stash. :)

Comment: Three certain things : death, taxes, and blame it on git ;)